# Issue with OpenXml WmlComparer when comparing documents with different numbering styles

Tags: ms-word, compare, openxml-sdk, openxml-powertools

I'm currently using the OpenXml library in C# to compare two Word documents utilizing the WmlComparer.Compare method. The comparison works well in most cases, but I'm encountering an issue specifically related to legal style numbering.

When comparing two documents, if one contains legal style numbering and the other doesn't, the resulting compared document loses the legal numbering entirely, without even maintaining a strikethrough format.

I've already implemented the comparison using WmlComparer.Compare and set the necessary comparison settings. However, I'm struggling to retain the legal style numbering or apply strikethrough formatting to the mismatched numbering when generating the compared document.
Here's a simplified version of the relevant part of my code:

Here's a simplified version of the relevant part of my code:

```
 WmlComparerSettings settings = new WmlComparerSettings
            {
                AuthorForRevisions = author,
                DetailThreshold = 0
            };

            var originalDoc = new WmlDocument(originalPath.ToString());
            var revisedDoc = new WmlDocument(revisedPath.ToString());

            WmlDocument comparedDoc = WmlComparer.Compare(originalDoc, revisedDoc, settings);
```

Comment: Pretty sure the reason this fails is that the code does a character-by-character of the teext it finds in the XML representation of the paragraph, but the numbering is *not contained* in that text - it is generated dynamically by Word using various numbering property elements/attributes in the paragraph properties element. I think the C# would have to be modified quite substantially to deal with that in the general case because the code needs to know what characters Word would generate for different numbering types....

Comment: ...it's certainly beyond my ability to fix, at least in a practical timescale, but you might be able to flag the problem in GitHub - perhaps Eric White had some tarting point code that might help, e.g. at https://github.com/OpenXmlDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/tree/vNext/OpenXmlPowerTools

Comment: I have flagged the problem on github
https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/issues/1634